# Php mysql page view counter

Tags: php, mysql

I try to make a simple page view counter.
Every time the page is refreshed, the number should increase +1.

When I execute the code in Phpmyadmin it all works fine. But in php, the counter is returned, but not incremented. What did I do wrong?

```
<?php
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$hostname = "hostname";
$dbname = "dbname";


// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE `Games` SET `Played`= `Played`+1 WHERE 'ID'='3'";

$sql = "SELECT `Played` FROM `Games` WHERE `ID` = 3";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "" . $row[Played]. "<br>";
}
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: Is this a typo? `"password;` <= missing quote. Plus, this is a column `WHERE 'ID'` not a value.

Comment: Remove the single quotes around `'ID'`

Comment: `$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));` would have signaled the syntax error.

Comment: I removed the password here, but no typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a `mysqli_query` call after you create the UPDATE string into the `$sql` variable. What you're doing right now is just overriding it with the SELECT query string.

```
[...]

$sql = "UPDATE `Games` SET `Played`= `Played`+1 WHERE `ID`='3'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

$sql = "SELECT `Played` FROM `Games` WHERE `ID` = 3";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

[...]
```

Comment: You forgot `WHERE 'ID'='3'`

Comment: It should reflect the answer ^ `WHERE 'ID'='3'";` to `WHERE ID='3'";` or use ticks `\`` instead of regular quotes `'`. Please edit your answer. Incorrect identifiers http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html

Comment: Even though this is correct, you haven't made a mention of the quotes around the "ID" column. So again; fix that please. It's not up to others to edit this for you; it's "your" answer.